# How to switch between python version Windows

Tags: python, windows

Im trying to switch between python versions `3.6.6` and `3.7.0` in windows. I tried `py -3.6.6` and doesn't work. Looked for options in `py -h`, found none. I saw a couple of answers for switching between python versions `2.x` and `3.x` by adding `#!python3` at the start of the file.

I'm able to switch between these by moving path variables up and down but I want to know if there is a option to switch between versions in `cmd` like there is `brew switch python version` in IOS.

Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

If You have python of the same version with different subversion e.g. 2.6, 3.7,.. 3.9. 
Use the below command to open specific python version's terminal in command prompt:

```
py -2.6
py -3.7
.
```

for installing modules in command prompt:

```
py -2.6 -m pip install <modules>
py -3.7 -m pip install <modules>
```

Comment: That's the real deal!

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is simply type `py -2` if you want to use python2, and `py -3` if you want to use python3.

Answer (score 2):

Change the path in environment variable after downloading python 3.7.0 in windows where you can find in the properties of My Computer in Advanced System Settings

Comment: That what I did moving them up and down. I'm just trying to learn if there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to use multiple versions of Python, or run different sets of packages in the Python environment, you should probably just use Anaconda to create them, for example:

```
    conda create -n py36 python=3.6 anaconda
```

then you can just switch between them using

```
    activate <your-environment-name>
```

Comment: I'm not into anaconda but does `conda create -n py36 python=3.6 anaconda` create a virtual environment?

Comment: Yes, if you first install Anaconda, it will have a default python environment, but typically you'd want to set up a separate environment with whatever version of python plus a set of packages needed for your task that also match the version for that environment.  The "-n py36" creates a new python environment called "py36", you can call it anything you like. The "python=3.6" is which version of the python interpreter to use. The "anaconda" and anything else is to select which packages to install in the newly created environment.