# Error: Failed building wheel for pysha3 while trying to install it or use conda

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, pip, anaconda

I am trying to setup a Jupyter Notebook data analytics project using GraphSense, and I am having pysha3 problems. I use Windows 11, both Python 3.11 and 3.10, the newest Conda version 23.7.2. One of the steps is I need to run the following command to create an environment from a YAML file:

`conda env create -f environment.yml`

The file can be found under C:\GitHubRepo*my_environment*\ and I changed directory to here.
It starts downloading, extracting packages, successfully preparing, executing, verifying, then there is an "Installing pip dependencies" problem:

```
Building wheel for pysha3 (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for pysha3 (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for pysha3
Successfully built graphsense-python
Failed to build pysha3

Pip subprocess error:
  Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/graphsense/graphsense-python 'C:\Users\*me*\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-bdcsrhjs'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

...

C:\Users\*me*\anaconda3\envs\*my_environment*\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.31.31103\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pysha3
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pysha3, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I noticed, that it tries to open files from my environment for the procedure, so I quit and just tried to install pysha3 with pip install pysha3 under my user directory, first with Python 3.11 which didn't work, based on other posts I switched to Python 3.10 with Anaconda and ran it in the Anaconda Prompt, and still:

```
Building wheel for pysha3 (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPY_WITH_KECCAK=1 -IC:\Users\*me*\anaconda3\envs\py310\include -IC:\Users\*me*\anaconda3\envs\py310\Include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /TcModules/_sha3/sha3module.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\Modules/_sha3/sha3module.obj
      sha3module.c
      C:\Users\*me*\anaconda3\envs\py310\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
 Building wheel for pysha3 (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.31.31103\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
```

So this doesn't work either, what can I do?

Comment: I have ran into this problem once again: while trying ```pip install coinaddrvalidator```, again: Building wheel for pysha3 (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I got it solved. It was a combination of two problems, that needed to be taken care of at the same time:

-some Visual Studio C++ tools are uninstalled (see: [Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018405/cannot-open-include-file-io-h-no-such-file-or-directory))

-Python 3.11 is incapable of building the wheels for pysha3, older version needs to be used (see e.g.: [Error while buliding pysha3 with pip? ERROR: Failed building wheel for pysha3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74369660/error-while-buliding-pysha3-with-pip-error-failed-building-wheel-for-pysha3))

I first installed the missing tools, then using `pyenv` I installed an older version of Python (see [How to install an older version of python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36809967/how-to-install-an-older-version-of-python), I also recommend installing via Hrvoje's comment) and switched temporarily to Python 3.10 to run the command (based on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52133694/19626271), and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling `python3.10-dev` or `python3.11-dev` first, and then reinstalling `pysha3`

Answer (score 0):

pysha3 package is deprecated, you should use [safe-pysha3](https://github.com/5afe/pysha3) instead which is compatible with newer Python version.